# Is bandwidth always taken from the site hosting the file?

Tags: iframe, youtube, web-hosting, bandwidth

If, for example, I use an iFrame to embed a YouTube video on a site, is it really true that the bandwidth is taken from, in this case, YouTube as it's the site hosting the file, and not from the site with the iFrame?

I just read about this here https://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/reduce-your-websites-bandwidth-and-storage-usage-92 but haven't found anything else on it.

Answer (score 1):

Try Chrome and the developer Tools > Tab "network".
There you can see exactly where a File/video/whatever is been downloaded.

A Youtube Video is downloaded from youtube.com and the HTML of your i Frame is downloaded from your server. The easyest Test is to hotlink some Images from other Websites, eg "https://stackoverflow.com/content/img/progress-dots.gif" als [image]. The developer Tool in Chrome (or FF or Opera or Safari (if you activate it), or even F12 in IE (...) is showing the source and much more.

Comment: Hi Eddi, you seem to be answering "Yes", in the case of the YouTube example, but also suggest that each image/browser combination needs to be tested, so answering "No", which would then contradict your answer to the YouTube example ... can you clarify?